# Are all convergent sequences bounded and monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know of the monotone convergence theorem, but does this mean that sequences converge only if they are bounded and monotone?

Comment: Bounded yes, Monotone no.

Comment: Example: $a_n = (-1/2)^n$ is convergent but not monotone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about the sequence

$$\frac{(-1)^n}n\quad ?$$

Answer (score 4):

If a sequence is convergent then it is bounded (**Hint:** take $\epsilon = 1$).

And $$\bigg(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2^2} , \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3^2}, \ldots\bigg)$$ converges but is not monotic.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence $(x_n)$ converges it is bounded (you should proove it showing that every element except a finite number of them of the sequence is at distance at most $1$ from the limit and then conclude).

But on the other hand, if $x_n:=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ $(n\geq 1$) then the sequence goes to $0$ at infinity but it is not monotone.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can choose some Cauchy sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb R$ which is alternating, or "jumps around." Then $\{a_n\}$ is bounded and converges but is not monotone.

For example:

$\{a_n\} = \frac 1n$ for odd $n$, $0$ for even $n$

$\{b_n\} = \frac 1 {n^2} \sin (n) $